# Positioned-fixed div not scrolling horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed div menu bar at the top of my page, when the screen is resized, the menubar isn't scrollable horizontally.

I've tried using the overflow setting, but this creates a separate scrollbar under the menubar.

I need my menubar fixed at the top of the page.

html:

```
<div style="position:fixed; width:100%; top:0;" id="menu-bar">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="70" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">
            <table width="990" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <tr>
                    <td width="400" valign="middle" align="left"><img src="images/logo.png" height="45" border="0" /></td>
                    <td width="50" valign="middle" align="left"></td>
                    <td class="menubox"><a href="#topofpage" class="topmenutext">Home</a></td>
                    <td class="menubox"><a href="#about" class="topmenutext">About</a></td>
                    <td class="menubox"><a href="#prices" class="topmenutext">Prices</a></td>  
                    <td class="menubox"><a href="#demo" class="topmenutext">Demo</a></td>
                    <td class="menubox"><a href="#contact" class="topmenutext">Contact</a></td>
                    <td class="menubox"><a href="#signup" class="topmenutext">Sign Up</a></td>
                    <td class="menubox"><a href="#login" class="topmenutext">Log In</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9zth81k9/)**

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your relevant code?

Comment: Perhaps you need to review [ask] questions on SO.

Comment: Sorry.... https://jsfiddle.net/9zth81k9/

Comment: Those days of tables layouts are (afortunatelly) over. I would recomend you to NOT use a complex nested table just to make your header. There are plenty of better, cleaner and specially much more flexible options out there.

Comment: Thought that might be the case, old habits die hard. Should I be using divs

Comment: [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered creating a fixed navbar using Bootstrap? It keeps the navigation bar at the top of the page and handles changes due to screen re-sizing (for smaller screens like phones) by creating a dropdown. It looks something like this: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

This is a pretty good tutorial to get you started:
https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/bootstrap-tutorial-navbar/

To get Bootstrap, I recommend adding the CDN code from this page between your head tags: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: Thanks, Jacqueline, nice article